# How to change Bethesda account in Doom Eternal?

Tags: steam, doom-eternal

I have Steam version of Doom Eternal.
Game prompted me to create Bethesda account so I did it via Steam overlay browser.
Game decided to eat underscore from my email and now it is stuck with invalid, and apparently already taken, email so game complains that "No username specified. Please complete account verification" with some funky guid in place of username.

Bethesda support is, of course, incapable of assisting with this issue.

I tried deleting userdata for Doom, didn't help.

Now I can't get that cute unicorn skin.

How can I enter correct Bethesda account into Doom Eternal?

Update:
It appears game automatically created Bethesda account on incorrect email (which appears to be taken...), and linked my Steam to it. Currently I can not link my Steam to my Bethesda account.

Be very careful when linking Doom Eternal to Bethesda account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is caused by Bethesda faulty DRM. If provided with non existing account, it will create one. When linking via Steam in-game browser DOOM Eternal stripped underscore from email which caused DRM to link Steam to invalid email.

There are two options to recover from this mess, and both are imperfect. Solution are not limited to Steam, linking to Playstation, XBox, and Nintendo, accounts works the same (according to Bethesda Support).

- relink Steam/Console to valid account, which might result in loss of **Additional Content**
- change email in invalid account to access it, which will be a problem if you have something linked to your valid account

Both actions require Bethesda support assistance. Both will require proving ownership of linked account, in Steam case I needed screenshot of purchase note (transaction ID) and username.

**Additional Content** is:

> ```
> Fallout 76 - All Game Progress Data, this includes characters, purchases and Fallout 1st membership.
> Skyrim / Fallout 4 - Only Creation Club purchases/Mods
> Rage 2 - Unlocked event skins and bonus content
> The Elder Scrolls: Legends - All Game Progress Data
> Quake Champions - All Game Progress Data
> The Elder Scrolls: Blades - All Game Progress Data
> Wolfenstein: Youngblood - Unlocked skins
> DOOM Eternal – Battlemode / Battlepass progress, Pre-order content, Deluxe Edition content
> Slayers Club - All points and activity
> ```

Bethesda Support confirmed that relinking Steam/Console will result in **Year One Pass**:

> If you accept the unlink request the you will lose the following DOOM
>   Eternal content
>
> DOOM Eternal – Battlemode / Battlepass progress, Pre-order content,
>   Deluxe Edition content Slayers Club - All points and activity
>
> The Deluxe Editon content is Year One Pass (Includes DLC 1 & 2),
>   Demonic Slayer Skin, and the Classic Weapons Sound Pack together.

Once Support changes email in Bethesda account to which your game is linked, you just have to confirm email.

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain, I did exactly the same but put ".com.com" accidentally. The only way I've found to do it is by submitting a ticket to Bethesda, they replied to me and said that they can unlink but I'd lose all my battlemode progress and I've put hours and hours into it. Not sure if it's worth it for me personally.

Comment: I am currently struggling through support tickets to clarify if losing "Deluxe Edition content" means I will lose season pass, that would be irritating.

Comment: I made it! The trick was to ignore game and focus on recovering account, Support can change its email. It just took a month and dozens of emails...